# Eclipse crashes on loading splash screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I was working on a new android project on eclipse, after the running the project eclipse crashes.

I restarted my Mac and tried starting eclipse again but now it's crashes on the loading splash screen and not starting at all.

Log File:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff916cc097, pid=913, tid=1287
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x5097]  objc_msgSend+0x17
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000101821000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1287, stack(0x00007fff5f400000,0x00007fff5fc00000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=0 (SEGV0), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers: RAX=0x000000011d0433b8, RBX=0x000000011d0433b8, RCX=0x00007fff950721c5, RDX=0x00000001005f7e40 RSP=0x00007fff5fbfa558, RBP=0x00007fff5fbfa5b0, RSI=0x00007fff950721c5, RDI=0x00000001005f7e40 R8 =0x00007fff5fbfa158, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x00007fff950721c5, R11=0xe000000000000000 R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007fff5fbfa618, R14=0x00007fff5fbfa5f0, R15=0x0000000101821000 RIP=0x00007fff916cc097, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, ERR=0x0000000000000000   TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fff5fbfa558) 0x00007fff5fbfa558:   000000011bfa7f6e 00000000000000f0 0x00007fff5fbfa568:   00007fff5fbfa5e0 00007fff950721c5 0x00007fff5fbfa578:   00000001005f7e40 00007fff5fbfa5f0 0x00007fff5fbfa588:   00000001018211e0 0000000000000000 0x00007fff5fbfa598:   0000000105af6cc3 0000000105adc310 0x00007fff5fbfa5a8:   000000011d0433b8 00007fff5fbfa600 0x00007fff5fbfa5b8:   0000000106022436 000000011c561f30 0x00007fff5fbfa5c8:   0000000101821000 00000007a0097588 0x00007fff5fbfa5d8:   000000010501eb1f 0000000000000003 0x00007fff5fbfa5e8:   00000007a0312e10 00000007a02f2c18 0x00007fff5fbfa5f8:   0000000000000000 00007fff5fbfa678 0x00007fff5fbfa608:   0000000105addfa0 0000000105addfa0 0x00007fff5fbfa618:   00007fff950721c5 00007fff5fbfa718 0x00007fff5fbfa628:   00000001005f7e40 0000000105adc310 0x00007fff5fbfa638:   00007fff5fbfa638 000000011cf9bc6f 0x00007fff5fbfa648:   00007fff5fbfa698 000000011c5c1bf0 0x00007fff5fbfa658:   0000000000000000 000000011cf9bca8 0x00007fff5fbfa668:   00007fff5fbfa618 00007fff5fbfa698 0x00007fff5fbfa678:   00007fff5fbfa6e8 0000000105ade210 0x00007fff5fbfa688:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007fff5fbfa698:   00000007ba0aae40 00000007a0097588 0x00007fff5fbfa6a8:   00007fff5fbfa6a8 0000000116a6a0e8 0x00007fff5fbfa6b8:   00007fff5fbfa718 000000011cfd7028 0x00007fff5fbfa6c8:   0000000000000000 0000000116a6a188 0x00007fff5fbfa6d8:   00007fff5fbfa698 00007fff5fbfa718 0x00007fff5fbfa6e8:   00007fff5fbfa760 0000000105ade210 0x00007fff5fbfa6f8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007fff5fbfa708:   0000000000000000 00000007ba0aae40 0x00007fff5fbfa718:   00000007a0097588 00007fff5fbfa720 0x00007fff5fbfa728:   000000011c5622cf 00007fff5fbfa788 0x00007fff5fbfa738:   000000011c566f28 0000000000000000 0x00007fff5fbfa748:   000000011c562358 00007fff5fbfa718 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fff916cc097) 0x00007fff916cc077:   90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 48 85 ff 2e 74 72 40 0x00007fff916cc087:   f6 c7 01 2e 0f 85 7e 00 00 00 4c 8b 1f 49 89 f2 0x00007fff916cc097:   45 23 53 18 49 c1 e2 04 4d 03 53 10 49 3b 32 75 0x00007fff916cc0a7:   04 41 ff 62 08 49 83 3a 00 74 74 4d 3b 53 10 74 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000011d0433b8 is an unknown value RBX=0x000000011d0433b8 is an unknown value RCX=0x00007fff950721c5: NSAppKitVersionNumber+0x4bb5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit at 0x00007fff9461d000 RDX=0x00000001005f7e40 is an unknown value RSP=0x00007fff5fbfa558 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000101821000 RBP=0x00007fff5fbfa5b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000101821000 RSI=0x00007fff950721c5: NSAppKitVersionNumber+0x4bb5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit at 0x00007fff9461d000 RDI=0x00000001005f7e40 is an unknown value R8
=0x00007fff5fbfa158 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000101821000 R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value R10=0x00007fff950721c5: NSAppKitVersionNumber+0x4bb5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit at 0x00007fff9461d000 R11=0xe000000000000000 is an unknown value R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R13=0x00007fff5fbfa618 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000101821000 R14=0x00007fff5fbfa5f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000101821000 R15=0x0000000101821000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fff5f400000,0x00007fff5fc00000],  sp=0x00007fff5fbfa558,  free space=8169k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x5097]  objc_msgSend+0x17 J 1358  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000106022436 [0x0000000106022380+0xb6] j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.contentView()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSView;+7 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getActiveShell()Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;+32 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display$4.run()V+15 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.timerProc(JJJ)J+105 J 4888 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJ)J (2612 bytes) @ 0x0000000105eed8b4 [0x0000000105ee53c0+0x84f4] v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2c5186] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2f9c4a] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2f230b] C  [libswt-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0x25f92]  callback+0x540 C  [libswt-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0x583d]  fn7_3+0x2f C  [Foundation+0x640f4] 
__NSFireTimer+0x60 C  [CoreFoundation+0xb53e4]  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__+0x14 C  [CoreFoundation+0xb4f1f]  __CFRunLoopDoTimer+0x47f C  [CoreFoundation+0x1265aa]  __CFRunLoopDoTimers+0x12a C  [CoreFoundation+0x706a5]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x5f5 C  [CoreFoundation+0x6fe75]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x135 C  [HIToolbox+0x2ea0d]  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+0xe2 C  [HIToolbox+0x2e685]  ReceiveNextEventCommon+0xad C  [HIToolbox+0x2e5bc] 
_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+0x41 C  [AppKit+0x2424e]  _DPSNextEvent+0x59a C  [AppKit+0x2389b] 
-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x7a C  [libswt-pi-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0x13d6a]  Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSendSuper__Lorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_objc_1super_2JJJJZ+0x7a j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/objc_super;JJJJZ)J+0 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(JJJJJJ)J+77 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(JJJJJJ)J+93 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2c5186] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2f9c4a] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2f230b] C  [libswt-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0x25f92]  callback+0x540 C  [libswt-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0xb525]  fn3_6+0x5a C  [libswt-pi-cocoa-4335.jnilib+0xfbc2]  Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSend__JJJJJZ+0x4f j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJJJJZ)J+0 j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(JLorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSDate;Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSString;Z)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSEvent;+36 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+98 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release()V+91 j  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose()V+50 j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+129 j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+119 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2c5186] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x489f3c] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x48a454] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x312600] j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100 j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6 j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56 j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211 j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126 j org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2c5186] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2f9ff0] V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2ebafb] C  [eclipse_1508.so+0x613c]  startJavaJNI+0x85a C  [eclipse_1508.so+0x4d6f]  startJavaVM+0x9 C  [eclipse_1508.so+0x32f9] 
_run+0x1203 C  [eclipse_1508.so+0x3ce2]  run+0x1b2 C  [eclipse+0x18e3]  original_main+0x711 C  [eclipse+0x1eb5]  main+0x4ce C  [eclipse+0x1090]  start+0x34

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) J 1358  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00000001060223c4 [0x0000000106022380+0x44] j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.contentView()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSView;+7 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getActiveShell()Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;+32 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display$4.run()V+15 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.timerProc(JJJ)J+105 J 4888 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJ)J (2612 bytes) @ 0x0000000105eed8b4 [0x0000000105ee53c0+0x84f4] v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/objc_super;JJJJZ)J+0 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(JJJJJJ)J+77 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(JJJJJJ)J+93 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJJJJZ)J+0 j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(JLorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSDate;Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSString;Z)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSEvent;+36 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+98 j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release()V+91 j  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose()V+50 j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+129 j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+119 j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100 j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6 j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56 j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211 j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126 j org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

How can I make my IDE work again ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Fixed it.

The problem was in the workspace .metadata folder (not sure where).
after using time machine to replace the folder with an older one eclipse backed to life.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, looks like you are running a new version of Java, on an older version of eclipse.
Please make sure , u are using latest versions, also update the JAVA_HOME and PATH. And try again.